# Connection String problems with OLEDB on a Remote Server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, connection-string, oledb

My Goal: Create a program which can copy a sharepoint database daily to an SQL server.
It should run from a server, and it should run daily.

Current Status: The sharepoint website is linked to a local copy of an accessDB file type accdb I open it with OleDB and the program runs locally generating the tables/columns/datatypes and copying the data.

Problem: When I take my solution and try to deploy it to a remote server it has a popup window asking for the user in the segment of code which opens the accessDB. I need this window to die.
The process must be automatic so it obviously cannot require human input to run.

I have spent the better part of a day trying to get this thing to go away and the program to run without it. No luck with google, StackOverflow, connectionstrings.com, or MSDN and a lot of other random websites.

---

Relevant code:

```
     public void openDataFromAccess(string connectionString, string tableName, string connectionString2)
     {            
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * from [" + tableName +"]";
        try
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240;
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    adapter.Dispose();
                }
```

The default connection string:

```
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Migration\Sharepoint Access SQL Batch Job\Database2.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
```

Things I have tried include:

```
   User Id=userid;Password=pass
   Persist Security Info=False;
   Delay Validation=TRUE
   Integrated Security=true;  
   Mode=Read;
```

and every other setting I could find in connection strings to no avail.

---

The popup has a save information setting but I would rather it be in the program, but the window does not save the passwork when I type it in manually but it does run. I cannot seem to get it to accept a hardcoded value??? 
Restarting the server and starting the service for Credential Manager and the registry editor does not help.

When I try to hardcode a user various errors occur such as:

"The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusivly by another program"

The user is not certified or some similar message like that (when the user should be, and I have tried several users and creating new users and admins etc. being very very careful to type it in as I thought was correctly) 
I have tried to edit the sharepoint admins but in my access when I try to edit permissions it links me to the sharepoint.

There is no JET registry I had to install the AccessDataBaseEngine_x64 manually. The program did not run on the server before this.

I am fairly sure the solution will be simple but what I have tried so far has not worked.

Ideas???

Comment: May I ask, why you don't use built in SQL Server Management Studio functionality to do a nightly backup in combination with a chronjob to import a backup to another instance of sql server?

Comment: Good question! 
That was the first thing I tried. 

-_- The SQL Server Management Studio cannot recognize the file type accdb and it seems this file type is not supported. I tried converting it to .mbd which is supported but it throws "unrecognized database format" also no luck googling a solution to that =/ If you know how to get around this error please tell me.

Comment: And why does it have to be .mdb format? Isn't a standard .bak backupfile not sufficient?
Adittional question: If you just want to copy Sharepoint databases from one server to another, why not use mirroring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was canceled so no solution necessary.

The database has some issues with authentication and this method does not support passing a specific user it seems, so I would throw it out and try using a sharepoint virtual server or some other method. I also hear the newer libraries will support sharepoint better.